# How do I extend these data structures in my word frequency program with LineNo (line the word occurs in) and CurLine (current line)?

Tags: permutation, ada

I have the program to print out each word in a file along with its frequency but I am trying to adjust it so that it also outputs which lines the word appears on.

I know I could create a Word_List type with 
words: Word_Array;   --unique words
Num_Words: Natural := 0;   -- How many unique words seen so far
curr_line: Natural := 1;

but I wanted to see if I could execute this without doing that and by adjusting my existing code.

```
procedure v3 is

   type Word is record 
      wlen: Natural := 45;       -- Length of the word
      count: Natural := 0;  -- Total number of occurrences of this word
      s: Unbounded_String;
      value: Unbounded_String;
            LineNo: Natural := 0;
   end record;

   type IntArray is array (1 .. 10) of Natural;
   type Word_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Word;


   --Sorting--
function "+" (S : String) return Unbounded_String renames To_Unbounded_String;
function "+" (S : Natural) return Unbounded_String renames To_Unbounded_String;

function "<" (L, R : Word) return Boolean is
 begin
 return L.s < R.s;
   end "<";

function "=" (L, R : Word) return Boolean is
 begin
 return L.s = R.s;
   end "=";

procedure Sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort (Natural, Word, Word_Array);  
   ----


    num_words : Integer;

    procedure get_words(wl: out Word_Array) is
    Input : File_Type;
   begin


      num_words := 0;
      Open (File => Input,
         Mode => In_File,
         Name => "input.txt");

      loop
         declare
            s : String := Get_Line(Input);
            found: Boolean := false;
            word : Unbounded_String;
            index : Integer := 0;
            word_len:Integer := 0;
            empty : Unbounded_String;
            space : Unbounded_String;
         begin
            -- process the contents of Line here.
            index := 1;

            for I in s'Range loop 
               word_len := word_len + 1;
               if (index = s'Length or s(I) = ' ') then 
                  if (s(I) /= ' ') then
                     word := word & s(I);
                  end if;
                  space := space & s(I);

                  found := false;
                  for i in 1 .. num_words loop
                     if word = wl(i).s then 
                        wl(i).count := wl(i).count + 1;
                        found := true;
                     end if;
                     exit when found;
                  end loop;

                  if not found and word /= empty then -- Add word to list
                     num_words := num_words + 1;
                     wl(num_words).s := word;
                     wl(num_words).wlen := word_len;
                     wl(num_words).count := 1;
                  end if;
                  word := empty;
                  word_len := 0;
               else 
                  word := word & s(I);
               end if;  
               index := index + 1;
            end loop;
         end;
      end loop;

      exception
      when End_Error =>
         if Is_Open(Input) then
            Close (Input);
         end if;

   END Get_Words;


   Data : Word_Array(1 .. 1000);
   Output : File_Type;
begin
   get_words(Data);
   Sort (Data);
   --Create(F, Ada.Text_IO.Out_File, "output.txt");
   Create (File => Output,
           Mode => Out_File,
           Name => "output.txt");
   for I in Data'Range loop
      if Data(I).wlen /= 45 then
         Put_Line(Output, To_String(Data(I).s & Integer'Image(Data(I).count)));
      end if;
   end loop;
   close(Output);
end v3;
```

So if the file had:

```
Hello Hello
Hello World
World World 
World
```

My current output is

```
Hello 3
World 4
```

I want my new output to be

```
Hello 1-2 wc: 3
World 2-3-4 wc: 4
```

Comment: Why not a map of string keys to items containing data about the string's location and count?

Comment: @trashgod’s suggestion is good: the data about the word's locations might be in a Vector indexed by, say, Positive of Positive line numbers. What do you do about words that appear more than once in one line? And, if you use a sorted map, won’t need to sort again.